# Can I use a WPF control in WinForms to achieve transparency effects?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, wpf-controls, winforms-interop

Is it possible to use WPF in WinForms, to implement the idea used in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008440/semi-transparent-custom-layout-panel). I am trying to create a semi-transparent panel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically yes - there are ways of [hosting WPF](http://nayyeri.net/host-wpf-controls-in-windows-forms) [in WinForms](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/hosting-wpf-controls-winforms) using [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

However, you're likely to run into problems with the transparency.  WPF's rendering is different to WinForms and, while you can make the WPF control transparent, the WinForms underneath aren't going to respect that.

Comment: +1 This is correct. You're going to run into a whole host of problems and end up with such a mess that you'll wish you just wrote the app in WPF to begin with. WinForms doesn't support transparency, and you're not going to get around it with a kludge solution like this.

Comment: Is there any workaround? I have completed almost 70% of the app, I cant go back make the whole program again in WPF.

Comment: @abcd: Depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. I'm not sure what the recent fascination with transparency and similar effects is all about. I've never seen an application that benefited from these "features", or the resources required to implement and run them. Layered windows are an option, as is the built-in mechanism WinForms provides for simulating transparency, wherein the background is drawn by the parent/container control. Alternatively, you could just punt the problem and create an image that is semi-transparent using a photo editor.

Comment: @Cody will I be be able to get semi-transparency with an image when the object behind the image is a moving picture

Comment: @abcd: You certainly can if you use an animated GIF. The built-in `PictureBox` control supports this perfectly well. You just need a single image, not two overlaid on top of one another in separate controls. If you absolutely have to do this with two images, you could consider drawing one on top of the other using the `Graphics.DrawImage` method. But you still won't get *partial* transparency, you'll just be able to see the background image *through* the clear regions of the top image.

Comment: @Cody Is it true that you can set the opacity of a png image via code in vb.net? I read this somewhere but don't remember where.

Comment: @abcd: Probably, although I've never tried it myself. You can do quite a bit with the GDI+ drawing functions. See [this link](http://www.geekpedia.com/code110_Set-Image-Opacity-Using-Csharp.html) for the code in C#. It should be easy to translate in to VB.NET. If you get stuck, try an [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Opacity` property of your WinForm to make it semitransparent.

Comment: Note in the question I have asked for a semi-transparent panel.