# Drawing a semi transparent panel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am trying to draw a semi transparent panel background image.
For this i took a panel and draw an image as background. Then i draw another panel above it( same size) and set it's background color semi transparent ( Color.FromArgb() ).
But the image of bottom panel is not showing. I guess my technique is not correct.

Is there any way to draw a panel background as semi transparent?

Here's the code of top panel.

```
private void panel6_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 101, 135, 196)), panel6.ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkBlue,
            e.ClipRectangle.Left,
            e.ClipRectangle.Top,
            panel6.Width - 1,
            panel6.Height - 1);
    }
```

Thank in advance :)

Solved:

I Draw some semi transparent line over the picture and it did the trick
here is my code

```
 private void panel5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = panel5.BackgroundImage;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(180, 255, 255, 255), img.Width);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, -1, -1, img.Width, img.Height);

    }
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate.That thread only gave answer to how to make a transparent background,not semi transparent.

Comment: Posted teh wrong one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008440/semi-transparent-custom-layout-panel?rq=1

Comment: Pretty unclear how you could "draw another panel above it".  The usual problem with transparency effects is that the top panel has the wrong Parent.  It must be the bottom panel, not the form.  Or just not bother at all and use the bottom panel's Paint event.

Comment: How to use bottom panel paint event to make it semi transpaeent?